# How to rename multiple files every day

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd, rename, filenames

I am trying to rename multiple files with a bat file.

i use the below code and works fine.

```
for %%a in (*.csv) do ren "%%~a" "%%~na Sea %%~xa"
```

Although the problem is that the script will run every day and will gradually add multiple times the word "Sea"

> ```
> I.E
>
> First Day 
>
> File name = "ho.csv"
> Script runs the first day and the output is : "ho Sea .csv"
>
> Second day
> File name "ho Sea .csv", "Go.csv"
> Script runs the second day and the output is : "ho Sea  Sea .csv", "Go Sea .csv"
> ```

I am not so experienced but most probable the solution would be easy something like an if to check the existing name...

Do you have any solution to propose regarding this?

Also is there any way to make the script run every day in a specific time?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] of your own coding attempts! According to your example, the new file name would not be `ho Sea.csv` but `ho Sea .csv`, so please clarify! To run a script periodically use the Windows Task Scheduler…

Comment: Hello @aschipfl thanks for your kind input. Indeed you are right i edited it on my post.    I tried to use the windows Task scheduler but the cmd window opens and nothing happens.

Comment: The example code you've posted does not produce/rename files on the first day like this `ho Sea.csv`, it produces them like this `ho Sea .csv`, which I would strongly suggest you do not do. On the second day, that file would then become, `ho Sea  Sea .csv`, not `ho Sea Sea .csv` as in your example, _(note the doublespace between `Sea` and `Sea`)_. You should change your rename command to `ren "%%~a" "%%~na Sea%%~xa"` for the names I think you mean to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your current command with :

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b ^| findstr /V ".*Sea\.csv"') do ren "%%~a" "%%~na Sea %%~xa"
```

Comment: Indeed there were issues. Edited answer.

Comment: Much better. Use `dir /b *.csv` to make it safer (avoid renaming other files than `.csv`)

Comment: …or even `dir /B /A:-D-H-S *.csv` to filter out directories, hidden and system files…

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your specific issue, is to exclude file basenames which already end with the string  `Sea` from being passed to the `Do` portion of your [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop). To do that, the simplest way would be to pipe the command through `findstr.exe`.

```powershell
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D *.csv ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /EILV " Sea.csv"') Do @Ren "%%G" "%%~nG Sea%%~xG"
```

---

However, using `Dir` can be problematic, due to the 'on by default' 8.3 file names. What this means is that the glob `*.csv` will match file extensions beginning with the case insensitive string `.csv`, not those which exactly match that case insensitive string. Whilst it may be unlikely that you will have other extensions beginning with `.csv`, I have seen `.csvt` files before. For safety therefore you should pipe the `Dir` results through another `findstr` to filter to only `.csv` first:

```powershell
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('"Dir /B /A:-D *.csv | %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /EIL ".csv" | %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /EILV " Sea.csv""') Do @Ren "%%G" "%%~nG Sea%%~xG"
```

To ignore 8.3 naming you could instead use the `where` command, *([windows-vista](/questions/tagged/windows-vista) and newer)*. However, `where.exe` has an additional potential issue, in that it will also match `.csv.ext`, where `.ext` will be each of those listed in the value of `%PATHEXT%` variable for the current environment. In order to prevent that you need to empty the `%PATHEXT%` variable, for that particular environment:

```powershell
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('"(Set PATHEXT=) & %__AppDir__%where.exe .:*.csv 2> NUL | %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /EILV " Sea.csv""') Do @Ren "%%G" "%%~nG Sea%%~xG"
```

I will, therefore, urge you to use either of the two lower examples, and not the version at the top of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this would be with PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system. PowerShell will be available. When you are confident that the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the Rename-Item command.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\src\t' |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch ' Sea\.' } |
        ForEach-Object {
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($_.BaseName + ' Sea' + $_.Extension) -WhatIf
        }
```

This code does not do anything if there is a name conflict. For example, on day 1 a `t.txt` file is renamed as `t Sea.txt`. If another `t.txt` file is placed into the directory on day 2, it cannot be renamed `t Sea.txt` because that file already exists.